# How to specify space or tab as separator in teamcity multiple parameter specification

Tags: teamcity

I want to add ability to teamcity user specify several maven goals for build configuration.

Sample of maven syntax for several goals is

```
mvn clean package
```

goals separated by space

How to specify space as separator in teamcity multiple value separator.
It seems configuration webform trims user input values.

[image: image says more than 1000 words]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution, use edit parameter window
and specify double spaces as value separator
[image]